# Ubuntu 10.04 - RVM won't set a default ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

I've managed to install RVM on a Linode VPS before, but after a rebuild I'm running in to all kind of problems and thought I'd see if anyone here could advise.

I'm trying to install RVM (and Ruby 1.9.2) on a Linode Ubuntu 10.04 (32 Bit) VPS.

I've tried following the instructions on many sites, such as http://web2linux.com/installing-rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/, for a single user or system wide install (system-wide preferred), but I always encounter the same error.

Ruby 1.9.2 compiles and installs correctly, and when I use

```
rvm 1.9.2
ruby-v
```

The following is returned:

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

The problem occurs when I try to set 1.9.2 to be the default system ruby using:

```
rvm --default 1.9.2
```

This returns the following errors:

```
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/irb': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/ri': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rdoc': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rake': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/erb': No such file or directory
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/rvm/bin/testrb': No such file or directory
```

I've put a full copy of the trace here: http://pastie.org/1170192

This is on a fresh VPS with nothing else installed, so rebuilding it and starting again is an option. I just need to know how to avoid this roadblock and make 1.9.2 the default system ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to create the directory /usr/local/rvm and make sure that the files in there can be modified/created by the group that should be allowed to use rvm. Some more info on a system wide RVM setup can be found at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/